# How to Show that this relation is not well defined.

Tags: functions, relations

We represent an element of the domain as an equivalence class $\bar x$, and use the notation $ \left[ x \right]$ for equivalence classes in the codomain. Show that this is not well defined.

> $ f: \Bbb Z_{4}  \rightarrow \Bbb Z_{6} \; \text{ given by, } f(\bar x) = \left[ 2x+1\right]$

My question is how do does one determine/ show that this is not a function? How does one show that this not one to one?

$f(\bar 0) =  2(0) +1 = [1]$

$f(\bar 1) = [3]$

$f(\bar 2) = [5]$

$f(\bar 3) = [7]$

$f(\bar 4) = [9]$

$f(\bar 5) = [11]$

$f(\bar 6) = [13]$

I also guessing here that if a number is a multiple of another then that may play a role in determining it if is one-one.

Comment: The theory behind this question is similar to that one. But the question itself is different. I did not know that this would merit a deletion.......

Comment: In your example $\overline 0= \overline 4$ and $[9] = [3] \ne [1]$.  So we have $[1] = f(\overline 0) = f(\overline 4) = [9] = [3] \ne [1]$.  This is a contradiction so f is not well-defined.

Comment: If you finish listing those out $f(\overline 4) = f(\overline 0); f(\overline 5) = f(\overline 1); etc.$ and you also have $[7] = [1]; [9]=[3]; [11]=[5]; [13] =[1]$.  Putting those together we get the incompatible results: $f(\overline 0) = [1]=f{\overline 4} = [9] = [3]=f{\overline 1} = f{\overline 5} = [11]=[5]=f{\overline 2} = ...$ which is utterly contradictory.  This definition doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ f(\overline{7}) = [15] = [3].$$
But 
$$ f(\overline{3}) = [7] = [1].$$
Since $\overline{7} = \overline{3}$, this is not well-defined.

Comment: The last line do you mean that $\bar 7 \not = \bar 3$ ? Since they are not multiples of each other?

Comment: $\overline 7 = \overline 3$ because $7 - 3 = 1*4$.  What isn't mentioned is $[1] \ne [3]$ because there is not integer $a$ so that $3 - 1 = 6*a$.  So we have $f(\overline 7)$ equalling two different unequal things.

Comment: where did you come up with $3-1 = 6 *a$, where did you derive 6? Could you not say $3-1 = 2*1$?

Comment: The definition of $[x] \in \mathbb Z_6$ is that $[x] = \{a| x - a = n*6 $ for some $n \}$.

Comment: Or if you prefer $[x] = x, x+ 6, x+ 12,....$  so $[1] = 1, 7, 13,....$ and $[3] = 3,6,12,...$.  These are not the same.  So $[1] \ne [3]$.

Comment: To paraphrase mcmathsadist's post.  $\overline 7 = 3,7,11,15...$ and $ f(\overline 7)=[2*7+1] = [15] = 3,6,15,21,...=[3]$.  But $\overline 7 = 3,7,11,15... = \overline 3$  and $f(\overline 3) = [2*3 + 1] = [7] = 1,7,13,19,25...$.  But $[3] = 3,6,15,21 ... \ne 1, 7,13, 19,25....=[1]$.  So this is not well defined because we can interpret $f(\overline 7) $ in two different incompatible ways.

Answer (score 1):

If we want to get technical.

$\overline 0 = \{a \in \mathbb Z|\exists n \in \mathbb Z: 0 - a = n*4 \}=\{...,-8,-4,0,4,8,12,....\}$

$0 \in \overline 0$ so

$f(\overline 0) = [2*0 + 1] = [1] = \{a \in \mathbb Z|\exists n \in \mathbb Z: 1 - a = n*6 \}=\{..., -5,1,7,13,....\}$

But $0 - 4 = 0-1*4$ so $4 \in \overline 0$.

So $f(\overline 0) = [2*4 + 1] = [9] = \{a \in \mathbb Z|\exists n \in \mathbb A: 9 - a = n*6\} = \{a \in \mathbb Z|\exists n \in \mathbb A: 3 - a = n*6\}=[3]=\{....-9, -3,3,9,15...\}$.

But $[3] = \{a \in \mathbb Z|\exists n \in \mathbb A: 3 - a = n*6\}=\{....-9, -3,3,9,15...\}\ne \{a \in \mathbb Z|\exists n \in \mathbb Z: 1 - a = n*6 \}=[1]=\{..., -5,1,7,13,....\}$

So we have define $f$ in such a way that $f(\overline 0)$ can be interpretted to  have at least two incompatible values.  Thus $f$ is not well-defined.

=====

If "$\overline 0 = \{a \in \mathbb Z|\exists n \in \mathbb Z: 0 - a = n*4 \}$" is too complicated looking, we can alternatively say $\overline 0$ is the class = {all multiples of 4} and $\overline x $ is the class = {all integers that are $x$ plus or minus a multiple of 4}.  Those definitions are *exactly* the same.

So $[y]$ is {all integers that are y plus or minus a multiple of 6}

So $f(\overline x) = [2x + 1]$ means "take the set of numbers that are $x$ plus or minus a multiple of 4-- and return that set of all numbers that are $2x + 1$ plus or minus a multiple of 6".

That statement is "not well-defined" because if we take different numbers that are $x$ plus or minus a multiple of 4 (example if we took $x-4$ instead of $x$) we'd get different sets.

Example: if we took $1$ we'd get the set "all numbers that are $3$ ($3= 2*1 + 1$) plus or minus a multiple of $6$"  but if we took $5$ (which is $1$ plus or minus a multiple of $4$) we'd get the set "all numbers that are $11$ ($11 = 2*5 + 1$) plus or minus a multiple of $6$".  That's a different set.

Comment: What is $n$ and $a$ for $\overline 0 = \{a \in \mathbb Z|\exists n \in \mathbb Z: 0 - a = n*4 \}$. What would be filled in for these?

Comment: I think this is a bit "too technical" for what the OP needs (as in, I don't think the OP is ready for a plate full of symbols). @LittleJon, you seem to be having the most issues with modular arithmetic (i.e., what $\bar a = \bar b$ means here; to be congruent modulo $4$). Perhaps you should backtrack and just spend some time strengthening your understanding of congruence/modular arithmetic.

Comment: n can be any integer at all. and a can be any multiple of 4.  $\overline x=$ every number that is $x$ plus a multiple of 4.  n and a do not have any single one value.  $\overline x$ = the set of all numbers, $a$, where $a - x$ is a multiple of 4.

Comment: Perhaps. I'm hoping the list of numbers help.  $\overline 0 = ....,-8,-4,0,4,8,12......$ and $\overline x = ..... x - 8, x-4, x, x+4 , x+ 8....$ is clear, I hope.  So defining $f(\overline x) = g(x)$ is usually (but not always) not well-defined because it isn't specified *which* x we should use.  We could use x-4, we could use x, or we could use x + 4,896.  In this case those give different results.  [2x + 1] is different from [2(x + 4) + 1] is different from [2(x + 4,896) + 1].